# Setting a Disqus thread author

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, disqus

In my web application I would like to set the author of a Disqus thread manually, so he (the author) receive notifications when people leave comments.

Is that achievable with Disqus? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches to this.

**1. Use the API to set the thread author**

This endpoint is used to update a thread - you'll need the author's Disqus username and the Disqus unique thread ID:

http://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/update/

You can acquire the Disqus thread ID using a custom identifier or URL using this endpoint:

http://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/details/

**2. Send the notification manually**

We have an example available which shows you how to do this using our js callback and a PHP script:

https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/tree/master/notifications

Comment: do you know if you set a disqus thread author will he automatically be subscribed to thread comments?

Comment: Yes, but like with all notifications these are under control of the user. They'll have to make sure they've turned on notifications for your site (not default) here: http://disqus.com/account/ (click notifications tab)

Comment: Yep! Feel free to reach out with any other questions anytime: developers at disqus dot com

Comment: Two years later, have yall made a `this.page.author` variable instead of having to whats described above?

Answer (score 1):

When you set your thread you should be able to define related information one of which is author. See the api here http://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/set/